# How to add Opencv XML file in a Qt Resorce file or it include in exe file?

Tags: opencv, qt5

I was trying to add OpenCV XML file in the Qt resource file, but it's not working that's why I was given path of the file manually.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little? Show some code? What _not working_ means? I'm pretty sure that you **can** make this work, but without further information it's just a too broad question.

Comment: with using qt resource for image :

qpm3.load(":/icons/1444766275_iWarning.png");

with out qt resource :

String face_cascade_name = "/home/lucifer/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "/home/lucifer/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When OpenCV reads a file, it will internally use the operating system's file open function `fopen` or similar, which cannot open QT resources https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155302/2079934. You should read the resource file with `QFile` and convert its contents to a `std::string`. Then, you can use OpenCV to parse the xml string https://stackoverflow.com/a/12729875/2079934.